# Can I change the value of a existing cookie?

Tags: javascript, jsp, jakarta-ee, cookies

I want to change the value of a `cookie` using `Javascript` which is created by a `servlet`. I have situation where 2 `textfields` are there one for Quantity & another for Price. First I push a cookie with name as BookID & value as Quantity(initially set to 1). But if user want to change quantity field then I have to modify the respecting cookie value. Situation is:

[image]

As you see every row has a save button. When I click this button it should multiply price & quantity and put the result into total. I can not use `form` tag because One `form` tag is already present for `Make Payment` Button. All websites like Flipcart,Homeshop18 will do this. Any idea about my situation?? Please suggest.

```
<form action="Pay.jsp" method="post">
<tr>
  <td><%= i+1 %></td>
  <td><img src="<%= image %>" width="55" height="73"/></td>
  <td><%= bookName %></td>
  <td><%= price %></td>
  <td><input type="text" name='quantity<%= i+1 %>' class="round" value="<%= qnty %>"/></td>
  <td><input type="text" name='total<%= i+1 %>' class="round" value="<%= totalPrice %>" readonly="readonly"/></td>
  <td>
      <a href="/ChangeCookie" class="table-actions-button ic-save"></a>
      <a href="#" class="table-actions-button ic-table-delete"></a>
  </td>
</tr>
<input type="submit" value="Pay"/>
</form>
```

`/ChangeCookie` is a servlet. It is look impossible to solve this provlem using `servlet` thats why I am Asking to `Javascripts Experts` that Is there any Process to change a `cookie` value by `Javascript` which is created by `Servlet`. If yes, then please put the code here I will test it.

Comment: Basically, you're implementing your shopping cart on cookies. No, don't do that!

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7215547/1344509) explained how to update/delete cookies.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is not with the implementation, rather with the architecture of it.

It is not a good idea to keep user interaction data on the client side, since it can be easily manipulated, copied or spoofed there.

If I were in your shoes, I would store only the user session id on the client side cookie and on the server side match that session id to the user id which will then point me to the data I keep on the server about the user status and interactions.

This will as a result increase the security of the application. Since generally server applications are flowing this way, you will find programming seamless without obstacles like you have asked for.

Hope this helps.