# How to set cookie (jquery cookie plugin) for last end point of audio player (time) before browser reload and play audio from last end point?

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio, cookies

I am trying to play music from last end point after each page is loaded. How to set cookie ([jquery cookie plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie)) for last end point of audio player (time) before browser reload and play audio from last end point? Not working on IE8 and 9.

```
<audio preload="auto" src="a.mp3" loop="true" autobuffer autoplay="true">
    Unsupported in Firefox
    </audio>
```

```
function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays)
    {
        var exdate=new Date();
        exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
        var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
        document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
    }

    function getCookie(c_name)
    {
        var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");
        for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++)
        {
          x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
          y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
          x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
          if (x==c_name)
            {
            return unescape(y);
            }
          }
    }

var song = document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0];
    var played = false;
    var tillPlayed = getCookie('timePlayed');
    function update()
    {
        if(!played){
            if(tillPlayed){
            song.currentTime = tillPlayed;
            song.play();
            played = true;
            }
            else {
                    song.play();
                    played = true;
            }
        }

        else {
        setCookie('timePlayed', song.currentTime);
        }
    }
    setInterval(update,1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).unload(function() {
    setCookie('timePlayed', song.currentTime);
});
```

You will need to add an unload event to your window if you want to have some last bit of logic execute when the browser gets reloaded or navigated away from;

If you would like to also know how you can acces your cookie and modify it refer to this link's answer [Cookie editing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7215547/how-to-update-and-delete-a-cookie)

Comment: I don't know but like this `$(window).unload(function() { $.cookie('timePlayed', song.currentTime); });` ? @Hano Johannes Rossouw

Comment: You can use it in this way, i used setCookie in the same way you used it in your method above, perhaps create a function that can obfuscate the cookie writing and the audio objects access. So that the function will access your song , get its current time and set your cookie then your unload event would only trigger your function.

Comment: the $.cookie you refered to is from a extension plugin for jquery called from jquery cookie which you can find here if you want it the easy way :D https://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/

Comment: can i do it with jquery https://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/ plugin? how? @Hano Johannes Rossouw

Comment: If you would like to know how that specific plugin works you can refer to this link http://www.sitepoint.com/eat-those-cookies-with-jquery/ the normal way without plugins to change a cookie would be to edit document.cookie += "time=" + "15:07"; something like that. the plugin is much cleaner and easier though than you having to edit the cookie string manually each time

Comment: I update my question. but why not working on IE8 and 9 ? working fine with other browser..

Comment: What version jquery are you using?

Comment: I am using jquery 1.7.1

Comment: Ok, check that your page has the <!DOCTYPE html> added to the top since the <audio> tag is a part of html 5. this might fix the problem for ie 9. But ie8 has some issues supporting all of the html 5 types that were added and would not work correctly since the browsers engine has long went out of support by microsoft before html 5 was fully documented.

Comment: Like that article i posted above mentioned, you can test whether cookies are enabled in the browser, write some value and try to read it back, if it does not give back your value cookies are most likely disabled. Please if you have different questions to you previous ones add a new question do now keep modifying your questions otherwise answers given will no longer have context and people might down vote you for it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82503/discussion-between-hano-johannes-rossouw-and-userknowmore).

Answer (score 0):

```
<body onbeforeunload="return setCookie()">

function setCookie(){
   setCookie('timePlayed', song.currentTime);
}
```

you can use before unload event