# automatic clear cache, cookie after css / javascript update on server

Tags: javascript, css, caching, cookies

Our eCommerce website is in the production but we do lots of changes on UI. problem is every time we update new css/js file, we need to clear our browser cache/cookie.It is ok because we know there is an update in our website. But users does not know that. So  we need to use cache / cookies but it should clear from user's browser whenever there is any change in js/css.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to update and delete a cookie ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7215547/how-to-update-and-delete-a-cookie)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clear the cache in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011605/clear-the-cache-in-javascript)