# Changing the value of a cookie not working

Tags: javascript, php, cookies

I have a method of tracking the download of a document using a `cookie`.

When the download of the document is complete the `cookie` is set to 'complete' using `php` using:

```
<?php
.... document created ...
setcookie("download", "complete", time() + (86400), "/"); // 86400 = 1 day
?>
```

This works and the `cookie` is set to 'complete'.

A javascript listener on the initial page is checking the `cookie` so that when it is set to 'complete' the loading gif will be hidden, and then reset the `cookie`:

```
<script>
    window.setInterval(function () {
        var cookie = $.cookie('download');  

        if (cookie !== null) {
            if (cookie == 'complete') {
                $(".loader").hide();
                    document.cookie = "download=waiting"; 
            }
        }

    }, 500); 
</script>
```

The loading gif disappears but the `cookie` does not change value. I have tried a number variations such as to delete it:

```
document.cookie = "download=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC";
```

but nothing seems to work. I suspect it is the format of the `cookie` is a little different when set with my `php` and then trying to change it in `javascript`. Any pointers?

UPDATE:

It seems this is working:

```
document.cookie = "download=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC; path=/";
```

Comment: You cannot update a cookie in js, you overwrite it take a look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7215547/how-to-update-and-delete-a-cookie