# Delete/update cookie on closing tab or button click using javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies, tabs, geoserver

I have an application, on a button click it navigates to geoserver webpage and that will be logged in page without asking any credentials to user. I had done this by setting cookie to browser. I had closed the geoserver tab and again click a button which opens geoserver page, this time it is not getting logged in since the old cookie is in browser. Is there anyway to remove the geoserver cookie on closing the geoserver webpage? or update the new cookie on button click?

Comment: May be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7215547/how-to-update-and-delete-a-cookie

Comment: New Cookie is getting created on button click but its not getting set or replaced since there is old cookie

Comment: What if your button sent a request to your server to provide a new `Set-Cookie`, which could have either a new value or a new `Expires` time or both...

Comment: @HarnishKumar you have to overwrite the cookie the cookie cannot be update or delete you have to overwrite it or set a expiry time to expire